# Monitor the latest log with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logging, error-handling

I'm trying to monitor the log of an app and send an alert if an error occurs. This is pretty simple.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem "X:\Log\" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "log"} | Select-Object -Last 1    
Get-Content $file.FullName -Tail 0 -Wait | `
ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "ERROR") {
     Send-Alert -Subject "ERROR in $file on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -Body $_
    }    
}
```

What is not so simple is that the app creates a file named like log-DD-MM.log meaning that if the service crashes and the app starts a new log file PowerShell will still try to tail the old $file which is still there, but data is not written to it.

Is there any way to handle this and always check the last file? I was thinking of a while but I might miss some info when rechecking.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the latest .log file using

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "X:\Log" -Filter '*.log'| Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Using `-Filter '*.log'` works much faster than using a Where-Object clause afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

final code:

```
$MonitorLog = { 
    Param($Path)
    function Send-Alert {
    Removed-Code
}
    Get-Content $Path -Tail 0 -Wait | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match "ERROR") {
            Send-Alert -Subject "ERROR in $Path on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -Body $_
        }
    }
}
while($true) {
    $file = Get-ChildItem "X:\Log\" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "log"} | Select-Object -Last 1
   if ($currentFile.fullname -ne $file.fullname) {
       if ($job) { $job | Stop-Job -PassThru | Remove-Job }
       $job = Start-Job $MonitorLog -ArgumentList $File.FullName
       $currentFile = $file
   }

   Start-Sleep ([timespan]'00:00:30.00').TotalSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch and add the `-Stop` Parameter to the `Get-Content` cmdlet, something like this:

```
try {
Get-Content $file.FullName -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch {
"File Deleted Do something else..." ## Find the new name and read it again with Get-Content...
}
```